# Android LiveWallpaper: load and draw various bitmaps efficiently (example: video)

Tags: android, bitmap, load, live, wallpaper

I am developing a live wallpaper that reproduces an animation (like a short video) on background.

Does anyone know how to efficiently load various full screen size bitmaps and draw them on canvas?
I have tried 2 approaches and both are not  very good.

---

Approach #1:
Load all bitmaps on wallpaper startup.

Problem: Memory excess limit (about 35MB) cant load more than 10 bitmaps. So animations lack of different images.

---

Approach #2:
Load only 2 bitmaps. On run time, paint bitmap, delete old bitmap, load new bitmap, repeat.

Problem: Consumes a lot of the system, (not memory, but slows down os in general), however it works because it doesn't exceed memory limit. But still, slows down the entire system.

example:

```
  Drawer.drawAll(res,c,p);
  res.removeOldBitmaps();
  res.loadNewBitmaps(wpservice,display);
```

A different approach i thought about is load resource on a separete thread, what do you guys think of that?  do you have any other solutions?

Cheers!

Comment: You could do with one Bitmap only too. This could be achieved if you preload images into memory as byte arrays (png compressed for example) and decode only one at a time. Should this speed up the decoding process a bit compared to loading from resources at least. But if you're into video alike outcome why not make a video and use MediaPlayer?

Comment: Hey, that's a good idea, i will try it out and see if there are any improvements. No, i cant use media player on a live wallpaper, i dont know if it is possible, and even if it is, i plan to do some animations. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Here i found a similar post with an intersteing question, however i havent tried it yet:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133306/android-live-wallpaper-animation
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133306/android-live-wallpaper-animation)

Comment: Just in case you get interested in trying out the MediaPlayer approach, it's doable with OpenGL ES 2.0 and SurfaceTexture (API 11+ only though) at least. Without OpenGL I have no idea is it possible to have MediaPlayer render its contents on wallpaper surface.

Comment: Ohh thanks, i will take a look. However i wanted the wallpaper to work from API 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the solution I found was the following:

Load images on runtime, 1 by 1.

And use this options:

```
/**Effective image decoder by chelin**/
public static Bitmap decodeResource(WallpaperService wpservice,int id){

    int scale=1;
    Resources res = wpservice.getResources();
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    o2.inSampleSize=scale;
    o2.inPurgeable = true;
    o2.inInputShareable = true;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id, o2);
}
```

Hope it works as it worked for me. Cheers!

Comment: If you don't care about transparency you can save memory by using Bitmap.Config.RGB_565